# What is $\int_0^{x} u^{-\alpha u}e^{\alpha( u-1)}\mathrm{d}u$?

Tags: integration

I am trying to find an expression for the following integral:

$$I(x) = \int_0^{x} u^{-\alpha u}e^{\alpha( u-1)}\mathrm{d}u,$$

where $\alpha >0$. I was able to find an approximation of this integral, using Laplace method, assuming $\alpha\gg 1$, but I was hoping that I could evaluate this integral without approximations. Probably not in terms of elementary functions, but perhaps in terms of an infinite series, in the same spirit as the sophomore's dream?

Here is my attempt so far:

\begin{align}
I(x)&=\int_0^{x} u^{-\alpha u}e^{\alpha( u-1)}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^{x}e^{-\alpha \left[u\left(\ln u-1\right)+1\right]}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^{-\alpha}\int_0^{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-\alpha)^n}{n!}u^n\left(\ln u-1\right)^n\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^{-\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^{x}\frac{(-\alpha)^n}{n!}u^n\left(\ln u-1\right)^n\mathrm{d}u,
\end{align}

where in the last line I swapped the infinite series with the integral since the series converges uniformly. However, I am not sure how to proceed next. I tried a few things (using the binomial theorem to split $(\ln u -1)^n$ but nothing brought an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Experimentally, you can get:

$$ \int_0^x u^{-\alpha u}e^{\alpha( u-1)}du=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-a)^n}{n!}\int_0^x u^n\ln^n(u)e^{a u}du$$

and consider the [lower incomplete $\gamma(a,x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cgamma%28a%2Cx%29) function:

$$\int_0^x u^r \ln^c(u)e^{au}du=\frac{d^c}{dr^c}\int_0^x x^u e^{au}du=\frac{d^c}{dr^c}a^{-r-1}(-1)^{-r}\gamma(r+1,-a x)$$

If $x\to\infty$:

$$\int_0^x u^r \ln^c(u)e^{au}du= \frac{d^c}{dr^c}a^{-r-1}(-1)^{-r}r!$$